# isEnabled() method always returns true

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the list of Strings for which the check boxes are enabled. But when i use isEnabled(), it always return true even for the disabled check boxes. And in output i get the list of all Strings present in that field.

Below is the code which i have written for it:-

```
@FindBy(css = "[class *= 'CheckboxTextAligned']")
    private List<WebElement> airportListCheckbox;

public void getEnabledValues() {
        for (WebElement elements : airportListCheckbox) {
            if(elements.isEnabled()==true) {
                for (WebElement airportText : airportListTextName) {
                    airportText.getText();
                    LOG.info(airportText.getText());                
                }
            }       
        }
```

HTML code is as below:-
**For Disabled checkboxes:-**

```
<label role="checkbox" aria-label="checkbox" class="inputs__CheckboxTextAligned undefined undefined">
<input type="checkbox" disabled checked>
<span class="inputs__box"><svg width="16px" height="16px" class="inputs__checkIcon" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
<path d="434z"></path></svg></span>
<span class="inputs__text">London City</span></label>
```

**for Enabled checkboxes:-**

```
<label role="checkbox" aria-label="checkbox" class="inputs__CheckboxTextAligned undefined undefined">
<input type="checkbox" checked="">
<span class="inputs__box"><svg width="16px" height="16px" class="inputs__checkIcon" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
<path d="133z"></path></svg></span>
<span class="inputs__text">London Gatwick</span></label>
```

Comment: Just a guess, is there a "isChecked()"?

Comment: Also, you never need `== true`

Comment: Use `elements.isDisplayed()` instead of 'elements.isEnabled()'

Comment: @AliCSE isDisplayed() method also returns the same o/p

Comment: I'd try debugging to find the proper attribute to use. As Steve mentioned above, a "isChecked" is normally used for checkboxes

Comment: Is that selector even getting the correct elements?

Comment: If you want an array of only enabled checkboxes, i would try `//input[@type='checkbox' and (not @disabled)]`  That's just untested air code, though.  Try that in chrome tools and see how many matches it finds (if any).

Comment: Try to use this `xpath` instead of `css` in `@FindBy` annotaion and leave the rest of the code as it is... `//label[contains(@class, 'CheckboxTextAligned')]/following::input`

Comment: @BillHileman Thanks a lot, i used the xapth as below
//*[@class='DropModal__content']//input[not(@disabled)]/following-sibling::span[1] and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your trying to verify the input node is enabled or disabled, isEnabled() checks for the disabled attribute on the element. If the attribute "disabled" is not present, it returns True.

Try the below code:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//label[contains(@class, 'CheckboxTextAligned')]/following::input")
private List<WebElement> airportListCheckbox;

public void getEnabledValues() {
for (WebElement elements : airportListCheckbox) {
    if(elements.isEnabled()) {
        for (WebElement airportText : airportListTextName) {
        airportText.getText();
        LOG.info(airportText.getText());                
        }
    }       
}
```

As you want to check the input node is enabled or not, you need to change your locator a bit because previosly you are try to check the label is enabled/disabled not the input node So you are getting always true.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ali, i changed the xpath as //*[@class='DropModal__content']//input[not(@disabled)]/following-sibling::span[1]
and now i am able to get the desired values.

Answer (score 0):

`IsEnabled()` method always look for **"disabled"**
attribute in the `WebElement`, otherwise it will always give `True` result.
If disabled attribute is not present in your locator then look for any other attribute in your element that explains field is disable or enable
Try this:

> WebElement.getAttribute("aria-disabled").equals("false")

and then use it accordingly.